# How to change the size of a textfield from an primeng columnFilter

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I wanted to display a small `textfield` under the column name in my `primeng` table using
`<p-folumnFilter type="text" field="data"> </p-columnfilter>`

But the text field is too big, and I wanted to make smaller.
appreciate any elp

I tried using `styleclasses`, `[style]` etx. Nothing worked or I just made it in the wrong way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.